# What is the best practice to load config files based on environment with Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a config file with content like the following:

```
App\Config\Config.js
{
    domain: "localhost",
    port: 8080
}
```

I can load `App\Config\Config.js` in my `index.html`. However, I need those values to match production.

What is the best practice to detect environment (e.g development/staging/production) on Ionic so I can load files accordingly?

Thank you.

Ps. I can do some tricks myself but I'm looking for the most widely accepted best practices if possible, such as relying on `.env` for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Best practise is to keep configuration properties in json file and asynchronously to wait for this configuration data to be loaded. like below

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfService {
  constructor(private _http:Http) {
  }

  getConfiguration() {
    return this._http.get('config.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

You can keep configuration file any place and you can give any name to this configuration file